# Getting contents of textbox in custom form

Tags: vba, ms-access-2003

Currently I've attached a function to a command button on my form which retrieves what the user inputs into the textbox on the form; this works fine but I want to emulate this behaviour with the ENTER key. How can I go about doing this?

I tried the Enter Property on the textbox but that only occurs when focus has been transfered to the textbox, not when i press enter after input.

I've read about the KeyUp event for VB but there's got to be an easier way - I've googled this but can't find what Im looking for. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at after update event?

Comment: No - I imagined that it should respond on default to the enter key being pressed. I'll examine that now

Comment: After Update is not enter only, it is after you leave the textbox by any means when you have changed data. It all depends in what you are doing.

Comment: The main target here is when the enter button is pressed - would after update suffice?

Comment: I need to know what you are doing before I can give a suitable answer. On the information you have given, all I can do is guess at possibilities.

Comment: look at the `Default` and `Cancel` properties of the button. Default executes the button click event occur on <Enter>, and Cancel executes the Click event on <ESC>

Comment: Ok - User enters some text into the text box on the form and presses enter - once enter is pressed it should launch some function to handle the input

Comment: @Sean Cheshire will examine that now

Comment: If the function occurs for the textbox, you want after update, if the function occurs for the command button, look at @SeanCheshire's comment. Please always provide a fairly detailed question.

Comment: @Remou sorted now - when with your suggestion of the after update. If you write this as an answer I ll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, the After Update event is suitable for working with data entered into a textbox, for example:

```
Private Sub txtFilter_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Filter = "Content " & Me.txtFilter.Text
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

However, if you need to edit or validate the data, Before Update is more suitable.

```
Private Sub txtText_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.txtText = "Invalid" Then
        Me.Undo
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```